# Searching by tags using the `or` operator requires a space char wrapping the `or`?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, tag-search

I was searching questions by tags (a set of related technology tags) and I realized that when using the `or` operator to agregate tags on my searching, it requires a space char wrapping each operators otherwise it won't be able to parse the query.

For example, this query won't be parsed properly.

```
[ionic-framework]or[ionic2]or[angularjs]or[angular2]or[typescript]
```

However, the next one will be:

```
[ionic-framework] or [ionic2] or [angularjs] or [angular2] or [typescript]
```

I'm not sure if it's a bug or feature (or even a confusion of my self) so correct me if I'm wrong.

Is it normal at all? I personally don't care much about such silly detail, but only it's not intuitive.

**UPDATE**

As it's been discussed with @ChristianGollhardt, actually it'd be a feature request, to add an exception to `or` operators to be allowed with no spaces wrapping it when between tags.

For example:

```
[ionic-framework]or[ionic2]or "apps" or[angularjs]or[angular2]
```

Anyways, it seems that it'd be waste of effort add such exception with a not so much valuable goal apparently. But, let's keep it as a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is normal at all. It is also needed:

Compare [`Score`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Score) with [`Sc or e`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Sc+or+e).

The last one would be the result for `Score` if we would change the behavior.

> but only it's not intuitive.

Operants should always be seperated from other contents. You do this naturally if you are coding.

Which one looks better and more readable?

- ```
  if(foo==42&&bar==43)
  ```
- ```
  if (foo == 42 && bar == 43)
  ```

Comment: I agree that it's way more readable, although both are equivalent. Also, about it being needed, not absolutely, you may agree with me that `Sc or e` is different than `[Sc]or[e]`. Tags seem to be a special case of this need because it's delimited by square brackets. As I said it doesn't bother me at all, but I consider this less intuitive and a good candidate for an exception. Anyways, I guess it's not a problem, is it? It look more like a `feature-request` or something like that.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro yeah, its a little bit different for tags, but if we would have a special behavior for it, wouldn't that be more confusing? What happens if you want to Combine `[Foo]or Bar`?

Comment: No, it's not confusing, it is only more permisive, is like a compiler that allows you to do `var a=1;` and also `var a = 1`. And if you wanted to combine `[Foo]or Bar` it wouldn't be a problem once you can parse the entire expression with no conflict or ambiguity like `TAG:Foo,OPERATOR:or,TEXT:Bar`. But it seems to me that it would be waste of effort to add such exception with a not so much valuable goal appearently.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of *not intuitive* was a little bit wrong. Maybe your Question should be tagged with `feature-request` instead of `bug`. I see your point. Sure it would be more permisive. However - as you said - maybe it is not worth the effort. @LenilsondeCastro

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've updated my question. Thank you mate. Should I consider your answer the correct? I don't know if it has a proper answer now :{D.

Comment: I don't know too @LenilsondeCastro. I would wait 1-2 days. Meta is more about opinions. The community is responsible by voting to decide if this is a proper answer or not. Welcome to meta by the way.

Comment: Ok then, I'll wait if somone has a different opinion. Thanks anyways.